# Transformar apenas numeros 0-9 de ascII para int

Tags: c++, stack

Tenho o seguinte código

```
string t_postfix = getPostfix();
Stack<int> operandos;    //pilha dos operandos
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){    //loop para pegar operando e realizar operações

        if(isdigit(t_postfix[i])){    // verifica se é um digito ou operando
            to_int = (t_postfix[i]-'0');
            operandos.push(to_int);    //em caso positivo salva na pilha operandos
        }
        else{    //em caso de um operador

            operandos.pop(v1);    //pega o primeiro elemento da pilha e remove


            operandos.pop(v2);    //pega o próximo elemento da pilha e remove
```

porem quando vou utilizar os valores de v1 e v2(int), faz uma operação e retorna o resultado para a pilha no topo, se os valores estão entre 0-9 a resposta vem em ascII porem se vem <0 ou >9 ai vem normalmente como int, teria algum modo de eu definir quais os caracteres são os que tem de trocar de ascII para int (0-9) e os que não tem? pois já usei

```
v1=v1-'0';
```

mas ai ele alterava os números nas contas

Comment: Por qual razão você faz: to_int = (t_postfix[i]-'0'); se não usa o resultado para nada?

Comment: a sim vou arrumar mas pego esses valores de uma string então para garantir que os números serão salvos como inteiros pois vem como resultado de uma função que obrigatoriamente tem de ser retornado em string

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, mas quando você faz if(isdigit(t_postfix[i])){  então o caractere existente em t_postfix[i] é um algarismo decimal. Caso contrário (o else do if) não é um algarismo.

Answer (score 0):

ao fazer o edit de um erro de escrita meu como foi notado "to_int = (t_postfix[i]-'0')" e não usar depois, deu certo e corrigiu o problema, o código acima postado já está funcionando corretamente após editado